# Data manipulation- Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataset:

- ```
      COL_1    COL_2    COL_2   COL_4   COL_4  COL_8    COL_9
      A         col2    col3    col4    col5
      B         col2    col3    col4    col5
      C         col2    col3    col4    col5
  ```

I need to move pairs of columns (COL_2 , COL_3 and then COL_4, COL_5) to COL_8 and COL_9 and copy the content of the 1st column (COL_1) as well as put the names of columns (COL_2, COL_4) to the other column (COL_10) this way:

- ```
     COL_1  COL_8   COL_9   COL10
     A       col2   col3    COL_2
     B       col2   col3    COL_2
     C       col2   col3    COL_2
     A       col4   col5    COL_4
     B       col4   col5    COL_4
     C       col4   col5    COL_4
  ```

Please note that some of column names in initial dataset are identical.
How can I do it using Python?

Comment: When you say move Col_2 to Col_8, Col_3 to Col_9 What happens to Coll_1 and Col_2, do they remain or are they to be removed?  Please clarify what you mean by "copy the content of the 1st column (COL_1) as well as put the names of columns (COL_2, COL_4) to the other column (COL_10)"

Comment: COL_1 remains, COL_2 as well as COL_4 should be removed. By "copy the content of the 1st column (COL_1)" I mean it should be copied and pasted in the COL_1 as you can see in the output in my question. By "put the names of columns (COL_2, COL_4) to the other column (COL_10)" I mean names of those columns should appear in the COL_10. Did my answer shed more light on the issue?

Comment: Names of columns COL_2 and COL_4 should be visible in the column COL_10 in the rows that are corresponding to the content of those columns in the new COL_8, COL_9. I know it may sound confusing. Please try to compare what I wrote with the output I placed in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the illustrated result you could use the function `concat` of pandas and create the new dataframe's column like this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

new_df['COL_1'] = pd.concat([df['COL_1'], df['COL_1']])
new_df['COL_8'] = pd.concat([df['COL_2'], df['COL_4']])
new_df['COL_9'] = pd.concat([df['COL_3'], df['COL_5']])
new_df['COL_10'] = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(np.repeat('COL_2', len(df))), pd.DataFrame(np.repeat('COL_4', len(df)))])
```

```
>>> new_df

  COL_1  COL_8   COL_9   COL_10
0     A   col2    col3    COL_2
1     B   col2    col3    COL_2
2     C   col2    col3    COL_2
0     A   col4    col5    COL_4
1     B   col4    col5    COL_4
2     C   col4    col5    COL_4
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this idea will not work, at least not for COL_10 since it's supposed to contain columns' names according to values of rows that are corresponding to them, which is COL_2 for rows with values col2 and col3 in columns COL_8 and COL_9, but thank you for you answer anyway.

Comment: I've updated the answer changing the construction of COL_10. Does it work for you or you though about something different?

Comment: Yes. The current output of COL_10 is exactly the one I was looking for. Thanks a million!

Comment: You're welcome! If this is what you were looking for you can select it as the solution of your question by clicking on the check mark beside the answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
part1 = df[['COL_1', 'COL_2']].set_axis([0,1,2], axis=1)
part2 = df[['COL_1', 'COL_4']].set_axis([0,1,2], axis=1)
new_df = pd.concat([part1, part2], ignore_index=True)
new_df[3] = new_df[1]
new_df.columns = ['COL_1', 'COL_8', 'COL_9', 'COL_10']
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
  COL_1 COL_8 COL_9 COL_10
0     A  col2  col3   col2
1     B  col2  col3   col2
2     C  col2  col3   col2
3     A  col4  col5   col4
4     B  col4  col5   col4
5     C  col4  col5   col4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is helpful indeed. However, the aim was to insert the names of columns COL_2 and COL_4 into COL_10 and there are values in the solution of yours. Values col2 and col3 are initially in columns named COL_2, so currently COL_10 should contain COL_2 (which is a name of columns) in the corresponding rows and so on. Do you know what can be done to achieve this result?